# How to format strings to numbers with apostrophe as group separator in Oracle

Tags: oracle, string-formatting, to-char

In Switzerland the number format is as following.

```
1'234.56
```

with the group separator the apostrophe or simple quote `'`.

How can I format a string in Oracle so it is shown in this way?

This works for the comma:

```
select to_char(1234.56, '999G999D99', q'[NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=.,]') from dual
```

I tried the same approach with the simple quote:

```
select to_char(1234.56, '999G999D99', q'[NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=.']') from dual
```

But I get this error:

```
ORA-12702: invalid NLS parameter string used in SQL function
12702. 00000 -  "invalid NLS parameter string used in SQL function"
*Cause:    An unknown parameter name or invalid value is specified in a NLS
           parameter string.
*Action:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select to_char(1234.56, '999G999D99', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=''.''''') from dual;
```

With a quote operator:

```
select to_char(1234.56, '999G999D99', q'[NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='.'']') from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select to_char(1234.56, '999G999D99', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=''.''''') from dual;
```